# Как отправить список из Python в MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, list

У меня есть такой код:

```
for i in [prices]:

    nick = [[i][0][j]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"] for j in range(10)]
```

Он выводит список имен с 1 по 10. Я хочу отправить этот список в MySQL. Когда я пытаюсь это сделать, мне выдается ошибка:

> Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted
> to a MySQL type

Код для отправки в БД такой:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sqlFormula = 'INSERT INTO test (user, password) VALUES (%s, %s)'
user1 = [(nick, 123)]

mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula, user1)
mydb.commit()
```

Так же я могу заменить этот код:

```
nick = [[i][0][j]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"] for j in range(10)]
```

На этот:

```
nick = [i][0][0]["data"][0]["advertiser"]["nickName"]
```

И тогда код сработает, но в БД отправится только первое имя.

Я предполагаю, что вся проблема в том, что я не указал, что для каждого элемента списка нужно создавать новую строку в MySQL. Если так, то как это указать? Или проблема в другом? Как тогда её возможно исправить?

Comment: Мы с вами вчера говорили на тему другого вопроса. Мне ту проблему уже рассказали здесь как исправить и то, что вы говорили было не совсем верно. Сейчас другая абсолютно проблема

Comment: Принципиально есть два варианта. Первый - слать в БД записи по одной, организуя итерацию по записям на стороне питона. Второй - сериализовать (скажем, в CSV или JSON) и слать весь массив, а в MySQL парсить на отдельные значения. Второе заведомо быстрее, но сложно, если MySQL 5-й версии.

Comment: То есть не получится как-то зациклить повторное создание записи user1 =                                            Правильно понимаю?

Comment: За первый вариант ничего не скажу, бо не работаю с питоном.

Comment: А 'print(nick)' и `print(type(nick))` не пробовали делать? Ну, или в отладке посмотреть.  Также странно выглядит `for i in [prices]:` зачем делать из `prices` одноэлементный список, чтобы внутри цикла этот единственный элемент и обработать?

Comment: А как будет правильней сделать? Просто разные варианты пробовал и работает только так. Вообще кроме nick там много еще переменных